# Regular expression to find and replace particular strings from a file

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex, node.js

i have an `html` file.in my file i have many src text's like

```
src="/home/ushus/dev/testResults/1/431619110/screenshot_0.png"
src="/home/ushus/dev/testResults/1/431619110/screenshot_1.png"
```

i need to replace `/home/ushus/dev` with  `/dave/homedave/`

like

```
/dave/homedave/testResults/1/431619110/screenshot_0.png"
/dave/homedave/testResults/1/431619110/screenshot_1.png"
```

html file sample

```
<span class="keyword">Scenario:</span> <span class="val">Open side menu</span></h3><ol><span class="embed"><a href="" onclick="img=document.getElementById('img_0'); img.style.display = (img.style.display == 'none' ? 'block' : 'none');return false">Timeout waiting for elements: imageView marked:'InstagramLogo.png'</a><br>&nbsp;
          <img id="img_0" style="display: none" src="/home/ushusadmin/testResults/1/431619110/screenshot_0.png"/></span><script>makeRed('cucumber-header');makeRed('scenario_1');</script><li id='features_sidemenu_feature_9' class='step failed'><div class="step_name">


<span class="keyword">Scenario:</span> <span class="val">Open side menu</span></h3><ol><span class="embed"><a href="" onclick="img=document.getElementById('img_0'); img.style.display = (img.style.display == 'none' ? 'block' : 'none');return false">Timeout waiting for elements: imageView marked:'InstagramLogo.png'</a><br>&nbsp;
          <img id="img_0" style="display: none" src="/home/ushusadmin/testResults/1/431619110/screenshot_1.png"/></span><script>makeRed('cucumber-header');makeRed('scenario_1');</script><li id='features_sidemenu_feature_9' class='step failed'><div class="step_name">
```

How it is possible with regular experssions(am working with `javascript ,node.js`)

Comment: http://www.regexr.com/ 
what have you tried so far?

Comment: @Psl You want the replacement on the fly or you want the changes saved in the html file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use following regex for it. [Backreferencing](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions#Using_Parenthesized_Substring_Matches) will help you to combine whole file name:

```
/src\s*=\s*(?:"|')\/home\/ushus\/dev\/([^"']*)/ig
```

Example how to use it:

```
var regex = /src\s*=\s*(?:"|')\/home\/ushus\/dev\/([^"']*)/ig,
    content = 'src="/home/ushus/dev/testResults/1/431619110/screenshot_0.png"'
            +'\nsrc="/home/ushus/dev/testResults/1/431619110/screenshot_1.png"';
console.log(content.replace(regex, 'src="/dave/homedave/$1"'));
```